# How to convert YUV422 image to JPEG using ffmpeg's libraries?

Tags: visual-c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a YUV422 image (YUV422_8_UYVY, unsigned ,unpacked, 16bpp)  in to jpeg using ffmpeg's ,[this is Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932581/how-to-convert-yuv420p-image-to-jpeg-using-ffmpegs-libraries) which I am following

Image size: 2448x2050
Original YUV Image: not able to upload as the format is YUV

(Original Image Decodec by ffmpeg command prompt)
Image:[This is original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwrcJ.jpg)

Image size: 2448x2050
reconstruct Image:[Reconstruct Image through above Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yowCu.jpg)

so the reconstruct image is not as the original image

my format is **UYVY** whereas supported format is **AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P**

*so what should be the correct format for UYVY input image...?*

`pCodecCtx->pix_fmt=AV_PIX_FMT_`?????

if i use pCodecCtx->pix_fmt=AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422;
i got an arrer saying

**[mjpeg @ 00c0b2a0] specified pixel format uyvy422 is invalid or not supported**

Comment: (AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422)-->(AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P)
the output generated file is still 0 kb and during conversion i got following message on console
 
1. deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did not range correctly
2. Warning : data is  not aligned! this can lead to a speed loss


av_image_alloc(RawPic->data,RawPic->linesize,in_width,in_height,src_pix_fmt, 16);

av_image_alloc(ScalePic->data,ScalePic->linesize,out_width,out_height,dst_pix_fmt, 1);

Answer (score 1):

You say the image format is "unpacked" (??), but at the same time you call it `YUV422_8_UYVY`, which suggests it's packed (i.e. not planar). The output you're getting suggests that it's packed.

FFmpeg's image encoders, in general, do not support packed input. You first need to make it planar. You have two options:

- convert it to planar YUV-4:2:2 (`AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P`) and input that into the encoder;
- convert it to planar YUV-4:2:0 (`AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P`) and input that into the encoder.

The first will preserve chroma subsampling (better quality), but the second will have better downstream support (in other applications, to decode the image). To convert the image, you use [libswscale](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/swscale_8h.html). The output image from that conversion can be input into the FFmpeg encoder.